# Who is considered as the father of modern astronomy?

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

Googling is giving me both Galileo Galilei and Nicolas Copernicus as the answer. I am sorry and will remove this question if it is an opinion based question.

Comment: It is opinion based, I'm afraid. What constitutes "modern astronomy" and who is the "father" of it are not things that can be decided in any other way.

Comment: If we must name someone, then IMO it's either Einstein or Hubble.

Comment: I like the Hubble answer.   I'd define modern astronomy as the discovery that the Universe extended beyond the Milky way.    Einstein was obviously huge.   I might call him the father of modern science.   (Opinion based, obviously).    Fritz Zwicky isn't a bad answer for the father of modern astronomy either.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Copernicus. He did his work maybe 100 years earlier and formulated the heliocentric view of the universe.